# Loading images and PDFs into BLOB from email attachment

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to learn how to save attachments from my gmail to Oracle Database BLOB server-side.

This is the part of my code:

```
static void InsertAttachment(String i_in, Message message) 
throws SQLException, IOException, MessagingException  
{
Object content = message.getContent();
if (content instanceof Multipart)
    {
    Multipart multipart = (Multipart)message.getContent();
    for (int i=0, n=multipart.getCount(); i<n; i++) 
        {
        Part part = multipart.getBodyPart(i);
        String disposition = part.getDisposition();
        if (Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(part.getDisposition())) 
           {
            String fileName = i_in+"_"+part.getFileName().replace(' ','_');
            String contentType = part.getContentType();
            String mimeType = contentType.substring(0,contentType.indexOf(";"));
            InputStream inStream = part.getInputStream();
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:default:connection:");
            PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("update email_table set blob = ? where id = ?");     
            ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] tempBuffer = new byte[1]; // 1 B
            int numRead;
            while ((numRead = inStream.read(tempBuffer)) != -1) {
                                outStream.write(tempBuffer);
                                 }
            byte[] attachment = outStream.toByteArray();
            pstmt.setBinaryStream(1, new ByteArrayInputStream(attachment),attachment.length); 
            pstmt.setString(2, i_in);
            pstmt.executeUpdate();
            conn.commit();
            pstmt.close();  
           }
        }
    }
}
```

It compiles and works without any errors. Moreover, all text files are loaded without any problems. I can read and save them, but all image or pdf attachments are saved as null by this code.

I upload Java Source by loadjava utility, and create pl/sql function to run this code on Oracle Database. I currently use Oracle Database 12.2.

I am new to this topic, could you help me understand what the problem is?

UPDATE:

Using advice by MT0 I've tried to download attachmens avoiding database.

I used this code:

```
static void InsertAttachment(String i_in, Message message) 
throws SQLException, IOException, MessagingException  
{
Object content = message.getContent();
if (content instanceof Multipart)
    {
    Multipart multipart = (Multipart)message.getContent();
    for (int i=0, n=multipart.getCount(); i<n; i++) 
        {
        Part part = multipart.getBodyPart(i);
        String disposition = part.getDisposition();
        if (Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(part.getDisposition())) 
           {
            String fileName = i_in+"_"+part.getFileName().replace(' ','_');
            String contentType = part.getContentType();
            String mimeType = contentType.substring(0,contentType.indexOf(";"));
            //new code starts here
            String destFilePath = "D:/Attachment/" + part.getFileName();
              FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(destFilePath);
              InputStream input = part.getInputStream();
              byte[] buffer = new byte[1];
              int byteRead;
              while ((byteRead = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                  output.write(buffer, 0, byteRead);
              }
              output.close();
           }
        }
    }
}
```

All files were succsesfully saved by this code.

So, the problem is related to the behavior of this code on the server.

Comment: Hi.. Do you see anything in the logs relating to this?

Comment: @robot_alien Hello. I know only about "AUDIT UPDATE" statement about logging in Oracle. Can you provide more info about where I can see something in logs and where I can find them?

Comment: If you strip out the database related code and output the file to standard output instead, does the code work for images and pdf attachments in Java outside the database? If yes, then the problem is somewhere in the database part of the code; and, if no, then the problem is on the Java side getting the input from the e-mail.

Comment: @MT0 Thank for your advice! I will test it.

Comment: @MT0 I have updated the question: the problem in the database part :(

Comment: Why not just use `pstmt.setBinaryStream(1, part.getInputStream() )` and skip the creation of a byte array as that just leads to denial of service attacks when people start sending 10Gb attachments and your application tries to load it all into memory and crashes.

Comment: Are your image / PDF files significantly bigger than your text files?  Not sure but Oracle may be trying to convert the bytearray into a varchar2 which has a max length of 32000, so for larger files this may fail.

Comment: @MT0 Thank you for your comment, I'll try to fix it.

Comment: @ShaunPeterson Yes, you are right. My test text files were about 100KB while pdf and image files were 1-2 MB.

Comment: In that case have a look at https://dzone.com/articles/lets-review-how-insert-clob-or they have a nice article on how to handle these

Comment: @ShaunPeterson Thank you for the link.